# Jquery Toggle On and Off

Tags: jquery

So I can use toggle do show/hide a dom element.
Now I need only when the toggle makes the element visible to make another action. How can I do that ?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? I have no idea what you're asking here.

Comment: Is it about being able to call a function on show and not on hide when using toggle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as naugtur says, you could use the version of toggle that allows you to specify exactly what you do when toggling each way.

Another option might be to test the visibility of the item in your existing toggle's event handler, e.g.:

```
$("#whatever").toggle(0, function() {
    if ( $(this).is(':visible')) {
        alert ("The thing is visible.");
    }
});
```

...will toggle "whatever", and then show the alert only when it's toggled visible.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want only to show an element, not toggle it show/hide. If this is correct, the solution is [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

The usage is the same as `toggle()`, but the function is `show()`

Answer (score 0):

It is true that selecting a dom element using a jQuery selector and using [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) will switch the visibility of this elment on and off:

```
$('div:first').toggle();
```

The atomic steps of toggle() are  [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).  So if you only want to show a hiodden element use

```
$('div:first').show();
```

for further reference have a look [at the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com).

If you want to add another action onToggle you will need to add a handler for this action.